# How to create a pivot table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot-table

I am looking to essentially create a pivot view using PostgreSQL, such that the table below:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Happy | Sad |
| Sad | Happy |
| Happy | Sad |

becomes

| Count | Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Happy | 2 | 1 |
| Sad | 1 | 2 |

I've been able to use case/when operators far enough such that I can see the counts under independent columns,

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN column1 = 'Happy' THEN 1 END) AS column1_Happy_count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN column1 = 'Sad' THEN 1 END) AS column1_Sad_count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN column2 = 'Happy' THEN 1 END) AS column2_Happy_count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN column2 = 'Sad' THEN 1 END) AS column2_Sad_count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN column3 = 'Happy' THEN 1 END) AS column3_Happy_count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN column3 = 'Sad' THEN 1 END) AS column3_Sad_count
FROM your_table;
```

but am missing the step to essentially each the pair of columns vertically.

I'm unable to use extensions such as tablefunc and crosstab.

Comment: Do all of those texts always appear in both columns as in your sample or it it possible texts occur in one column only?

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/B3CNIoJO):

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  column_a varchar(10),
  column_b varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO my_table (column_a, column_b)
VALUES ('Happy', 'Sad'),
       ('Sad', 'Happy'),
       ('Happy', 'Sad'),
       ('Good', 'Bad');

WITH DataSource (col, val) AS
(
     SELECT 'a', column_a
     FROM my_table
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'b', column_b
     FROM my_table
)
SELECT uniq.val AS "Count"
      ,MAX(case when counts.col = 'a' then counts end) AS "Column A"
      ,MAX(case when counts.col = 'b' then counts end) AS "Column B"
FROM
(
     SELECT DISTINCT val
     FROM DataSource
) uniq
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT col
         ,val
         ,COUNT(*) counts
   FROM DataSource
   GROUP BY col
          ,val
) counts
  ON uniq.val = counts.val
GROUP BY uniq.val
```

will give you this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may aggregate for ColumnA, aggregate for ColumnB then do a full join as the following:

```
select coalesce(A.ColumnA ,B.ColumnB) as "Count",
       A.cnt as "Column A",
       B.cnt as "Column B"
from
(
  select ColumnA, count(*) cnt
  from tbl_name
  group by ColumnA
) A
full join 
(
  select ColumnB, count(*) cnt
  from tbl_name
  group by ColumnB
) B
on A.ColumnA = B.ColumnB
```

If the distinct values in ColumnA are the same as the distinct values of ColumnB then you can use *join* instead of the *full join*.

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/l7z9yR4z).